# MySQL select from db efficiency and time-consumption

Tags: sql, mysql

Which one of those will take the least amount of time?

1.

```
q = 'SELECT * FROM table;'
result = db->query(q)
while(row = mysql_fetch_assoc(result))
{
userName = row['userName'];
userPassword = row['userPassword'];
if (enteredN==userName && enteredP==userPassword)
return true;
return false;
}
```

2.

```
q = 'select * from table where userName='.enteredN.' and userPassword='.enteredP.';'
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is guaranteed to be significantly faster on just about any database management system.  You may not notice a difference if you have just a few rows in the table, but when you get to have thousands of rows, it will become quite obvious.

As a general rule, you should let the database management system handle filtering, grouping, and sorting that you need; database management systems are designed to do those things and are generally highly optimized.

If this is a frequently used query, make sure you use an index on the unique `username` field.

As soulmerge brings up, you do need to be careful with SQL injection; [see the PHP Manual for information how to protect against it](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  While you're at it, you should seriously consider storing password hashes, not the passwords themselves; the [MySQL Manual has information on various functions that can help you do this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html).

Comment: Unless, of course `enteredN == "' OR 1 OR '"` and `enteredP == "' OR 1 OR '"`, that might take longer ...

Comment: Also make sure you check the fields for SQL injection attacts

Answer (score 1):

Number 2 is bound to be much, **much!**, faster.  (unless the table only contains a few rows)

It is not only be **SQL servers are very efficient at filtering** (and they can use indexes etc. which the loop in #1 doesn't have access to),  but also because #1 may cause **a very significant amount of data be transferred from the server to the php application**.

Furthermore solution #1 would cause all the login credentials of the users to transit on the wire, exposing them to possible snooping, somewhere along the line...  Do note that solution #2 also incur a potential security risk if the channel between SQL server and application is not secure; this risk is somewhat lessened because 100% of the accounts details are not transmitted with every single login attempt.

Beyond this risk (which speaks to internal security), there is also the very real risk of **SQL injection** from fully outside attackers (as pointed out by others in this post). This however can be fully addressed by escaping the  single quote characters contained within  end-users supplied strings.

Comment: If network-snooping is a problem, solution 1 is a disaster... but 2 ain't that hot either, as one user's id and password are still being sent to the db -- you really need a secure connection with the DB if you're ever going to exchange sensitive data!

Comment: @Alex. Yes, agreed! `#2 is a security risk as well`, if only a bit lessened because 100% of the accounts details do not transit on the wire with every single login attempt. I was only trying to find more reasons to make #1 look bad ;-)